# How to Implement Google Places API For iOS?

Tags: iphone, google-maps-sdk-ios

i want to implement (Auto Complete) suggested places of google while typing on textfield how to implement it using api key ?

for that i have downloaded google map sdk for ios 1.9.1 and put the api key into AppDelegate.m but i am anable to get the code following -

https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

Inside your **-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField** method of uitextfield delegate methods, write the below code:-

```
GMSPlacesClient *placesClient= [[GMSPlacesClient alloc] init];

[placesClient autocompleteQuery:textField.text bounds:nil
                                               filter:kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterNoFilter
                                       callback:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
                                           if (error != nil) {
                                               NSLog(@"Autocomplete error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                               return;
                                           }

                                           for (GMSAutocompletePrediction* result in results) {

                                                NSLog(@"Result '%@' with placeID %@", result.attributedFullText.string, result.placeID);
                                           }
                                       }];
```

Comment: have you imported GoogleMaps header file?